# Autowire a default implementation if implemenation bean is not found

Tags: java, spring

I have an interface with 2 default methods. If the implementation is not found, I wish autowire a proxy bean with these 2 default methods. Is this possible in spring?

Comment: autowire two of them. if (nonDefault == null) useDefault

Comment: Interesting. Not sure that such behaviour is possible with Spring.

Comment: This is the general idea behind auto-configuration and the conditional registration described in talex's answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to define bean in some configuration

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public Foo foo(){
    return new Foo() {};
}
```

where `Foo` is your interface.

Comment: This requires Spring Boot (specifically `spring-boot-autoconfigure`), not just Spring Core.